Webform 6.2.7 Date list Start Date must be before End Date
I have two dates "From" and "To".
Would like to make sure "TO" is greater than "FROM".
Using the Form Validation for "Date List" field "Date/Time minimum" of [date.from] in the TO field does nothing.
I have tried to create a twig, which I am certainly not a programmer using various combinations of {{date.from |date('HTML Month') >= {{date.to |date('HTML Month')}} - I am trying to learn???? HTML Month is defined in the Configuration.
Is there not a simple way to make sure each "TO" field is >= each "FROM" field?
I have 14 "FROM" Fields and 14 "TO" fields.
I need to compare the 1st line of "FROM" compare to "TO" then the second line of "FROM" to the second line of "TO" and so forth.
I am by no means a programmer but have tried various combinations of
[% if data.from | date('d/Y') >= data.to | date ('d/Y') % } without any success.
Seems cumbersome to have to create a Computed Twig for each "TO" fields.
Any suggestions or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks so very much in advance for any assistance......

I don't understand this question as written. You have a working solution but you want a "simple check". What does that mean?

The current solution means I have to create a Computed twig for each of the 28 date questions. Plus the computed twig is only giving a message the To date must be after the From date. It is not restricting them from moving forward. Sorry I did not make that clear.

You should add that information to the Question.
